# Why is GNU Readline messing up ANSI color codes?

Tags: c++, c, libreadline

I'm trying to use GNU Readline with a colored prompt. Boiled down to a minimal test case, my `readline()` invocation looks like this:

```cpp
readline("\x1b[34m" "prompt>" "\x1b[m");
```

I expected to see a prompt like this (just imagine it being blue):

```
prompt>
```

but instead I see:

```
[34mprompt>[m
```

I read about prompt expansion in the docs, and thought something weird might be happening there. But the expanded prompt is fine, and this works as expected:

```cpp
rl_set_prompt("\x1b[34m" "prompt>" "\x1b[m");
printf("%s", rl_prompt); // Prints "prompt>" in blue
```

This happens both in Gnome Terminal and Xterm. I'm using libreadline 7 on Ubuntu 18.04. I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on here, and nobody online seems to be having this problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.  I don't have a Gnome Terminal immediately at my fingertips, but I tested in an XTerm, in a KDE Konsole, and in a non-graphical Linux session, and in every case, the prompt emitted by `readline("\x1b[34m" "prompt>" "\x1b[m");` was colored blue, and the visible text was only "prompt>".  The appearance was identical to what I got by printing the same string with `puts()`.  Perhaps a [mcve] would help.

Comment: a lot depends on the `termcap` file and the actual terminal you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I might never know what was going wrong. I had fully cleaned the build on my project multiple times while testing this (regenerating whole CMake build tree, etc.), but simply deleting and re-downloading my own repo has fixed this.